# Why does this piece of c++ not find the struct member 'filename'?

Tags: c++, vector, struct, constants

```
            for (torrent_info::file_iterator i = t.begin_files();
                    i != t.end_files(); ++i, ++index)
            {
                    int first = t.map_file(index, 0, 1).piece;
                    int last = t.map_file(index, i->size - 1, 1).piece;
                    std::cout << "  " << std::setw(11) << i->size
                            << " " << i.filename() << "[ " << first << ", "
                            << last << " ]\n";
            }
```

compiling gives me the following error:

```
error: ‘class __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const libtorrent::internal_file_entry*, std::vector<libtorrent::internal_file_entry, std::allocator<libtorrent::internal_file_entry> > >’ has no member named ‘filename’
```

AFAICS `i` is a constant `internal_file_entry` struct whose header code lives [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/libtorrent/code/8213/tree/tags/libtorrent-0_16_9/src/file_storage.cpp#l156) in the open source libtorrent project. I'm just looking at C++ for the first time but I can't for the 
life of me work out why the above call to `i.filename()` fails at compile time?

Comment: Dereferencing iterators: `i->filename`.

Comment: `i` is a `torrent_info::file_iterator` not an `internal_file_entry`, it says so right there in your code, and the error message also tells you it's an iterator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`i` is an iterator that points at an `internal_file_entry` - it must be dereferenced. Access `filename` like so:

```
i->filename
```

This is equivalent to:

```
(*i).filename
```